# Failed to compile application

Tags: flutter, compilation

I just started programming Flutter. I get this error while running the program in web .

Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Failed to compile application.

Exited (-1073741795).

Nothing happens when I use this command
flutter run -d chrome

Comment: Can you try running `flutter doctor` and provide its output?

Answer (score 0):

Run Without Debugging:
Try running your Flutter web application without debugging to see if the issue is related to the debugging process.

```
flutter run -d chrome --release
```

Comment: Nothing happens, the program does not execute anything